Establishing a relation of zeros of a symmetric entire function
Let $f:\mathbb{C}^2 \to
\mathbb{C}$ denoted by $f(s,t)$ be an entire function with following properties:

$f(s,t)=f(t,s)$
Infinite number of zeros with no accumulation of zeros.
The locus of zeros in $s$ of $f(s,t)$ as we change $t$ is continuous and doesn't shoot off to infinity for finite change in $t$

Therefore by Weierstrass factorization theorem for a particular value of $t$, $f(s,t)=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}{A_i(s,t)\big(s-B_i(t)\big)}$ where $A_i(s,t)$ makes the product convergent since we have infinite number of zeros. By using property $1$ we get $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{A_i(s,t)\big(s-B_i(t)\big)}{A_i(t,s)\big(t-B_i(s)\big)}=1$$
For finite number of zeros $\prod_{i=1}^{N}\big(s-B_i(t)\big)$ because of property 3 it is a symmetric polynomial is $s,t$ this implies $$\prod_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\big(s-B_i(t)\big)}{\big(t-B_i(s)\big)}=1$$
I'm trying to establish the same relation for infinite number of zeros. For infinite number of zeros I can't use above argument of symmetric polynomial. Can someone tell me what machinery I can look up for proving this statement or a hint towards proving this statement or is it some known property of such symmetric functions. Thanks

what does $2$ (with no accumulation of zeros) mean in this context exactly? entire functions in two variables do not have isolated zeroes
